# Why is there whitespace when using .split() on string with the split term in consecutive order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I noticed that when I did `"heelo".split("e")`, it would return `['h', '', 'lo']`. Why is there an empty/a whitespace item in the list? Shouldn't it have been `['h', 'lo']`?

I am confused on why I received that result, instead of what I had expected and would appreciate if someone could explain me the functionality of `split` better.

Comment: There is an explanation over at the `split` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, '1,,2'.split(',') returns ['1', '', '2'])

Your string is divided between the first `e` and second `e`, but there is no character there, so you get an empty character back `''`

Answer (score 0):

It takes into account the first `'e'` separates the `'h'` but the letter adjacent to it is also an `'e'`, but there is no letter between the first and second `'e'` so you get an empty string.

If we add one more `'e'`:

```py
"heeelo".split("e")

['h', '', '', 'lo']
```

It returns two empty strings between the three `'e'`s.